# How to get Svn Changed file contents

Tags: svn, xslt, xml-parsing, cruisecontrol.net

I have used following command

```
svn diff D:\QATV2Demo -r 12414:12416
```

This gives me following result text file

Index: D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild

```
 ===================================================================

--- D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12414)

+++ D:/QATV2Demo/Main.msbuild   (revision 12416)
```

@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@

```
 AssemblyFile="$(ToolsBinPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll" />
<PropertyGroup>
-    <FxCop_CriticalErrors>10</FxCop_CriticalErrors>
+    <FxCop_CriticalErrors>0</FxCop_CriticalErrors>
<FxCop_Errors>0</FxCop_Errors>
  <FxCop_CriticalWarnings>0</FxCop_CriticalWarnings>
   <FxCop_Warnings>0</FxCop_Warnings>     


Index: D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs
===================================================================
--- D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs       (revision 12414)
+++ D:/QATV2Demo/QATV2Demo/QATConstant.cs       (revision 12416)
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
 {
     public static readonly string PAGE_DATA_DROP_DOWN_MODE = "D";
     public static readonly string PAGE_DATA_GRID_MODE = "G";
-        public static readonly string REPORT = "Report";
+        public static readonly string REPORT = "Report1";
    public static readonly string ITEM_COUNT = "ItemCount";
 }
 }
```

Now i need to extract those - and + lines that shows me actual content difference. how does i can do this is there any command that give me this result in XML format so that i can parse it by xslt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

svn diff has an --xml flag for outputting in xml. You can then merge the xml into the cruisecontrol build log and transform it with xsl. This is useful when the repositories you need diffs for are disconnected from the source controls of the cruisecontrol project.